# Getting bad file descriptor error while using fs.openFileSync in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, exceljs

I am putting the data from xlsx file into csv file. This is my code:-

```
const file = fs.openSync('/home/rahul/example/sample.csv', 'w')
const workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile( path.join(__dirname, '' + args.filename)).then(function() {

    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('sheet3');

    worksheet.eachRow(function(row){
        try{
            const buffer = array2CsvLine(row.values)
            fs.writeSync(file, buffer, { flag: 'a' })
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log('error related to fs.writeSync function')
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
    //fs.closeSync(file)
})
fs.closeSync(file)
```

it is giving me this error:-

```
error related to fs.writeSync function
{ Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
    at Object.writeSync (fs.js:569:3)
    at /home/rahul/min-wage/xls2csv.js:73:16
    at _rows.forEach.row (/home/rahul/min-wage/node_modules/exceljs/lib/doc/worksheet.js:515:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Worksheet.eachRow (/home/rahul/min-wage/node_modules/exceljs/lib/doc/worksheet.js:513:18)
    at /home/rahul/min-wage/xls2csv.js:70:15 errno: -9, syscall: 'write', code: 'EBADF' }
```

But if I use the commented `fs.closeSync(file)`, then it works fine. I don't know why is this happening? I think, I can close file at global place too.

Comment: What is `file`? There is nothing in this code that allocates it, or passes it in as argument.

Comment: I have edited the code, please look it one more time.

Comment: thanks. I would recommend turning this into a [mcve], because either this only happens when you're using exceljs, in which case you'll want to file an issue with the folks that make that, or it happens even when using nothing special, in which case this code is far more complicated than it needs to be. (and sure, figuring out how to hardcode values that exceljs generates takes a few runs with some console logs, but also, only a few runs with some console logs. Especially since you don't need more than two rows faked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to:

```
fs.closeSync(file)
```

...is called before the promise resolves. Just remove it from the last line and uncomment the other call inside the promise.